# Let $f \in L(\mathbb{R}), \ f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)$ exists. Show $\frac{f(x)}{x}\in L(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis

This is what I try:
\begin{align}
f'(0) = \frac{f(0+x)-f(0)}{x}=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\frac{f(x)}{x}
\end{align}
But it still not enough to say $\frac{f(x)}{x} $ is integrable
Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is differentiable at the origin, then there exists $\delta>0$ such that
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}-f'(0)\right| \leq 1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{|f(x)-f(0)|}{|x|} \leq 1 +|f'(0)|
\end{align} 
whenever $|x|<\delta$. 
Observe
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\ dx = \int_{|x|\leq \delta}\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\ dx+\int_{|x|\geq \delta} \frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\ dx = I_1+I_2.
\end{align}
For $I_2$, we have
\begin{align}
I_2 \leq \frac{1}{\delta}\int_{|x|\geq \delta}|f(x)|\ dx<\infty.
\end{align}
For $I_1$, we have
\begin{align}
\int_{|x|\leq \delta} \frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\ dx = \int_{|x|\leq \delta}  \frac{|f(x)-f(0)|}{|x|}\ dx \leq \ 2\delta(1+|f'(0)|). 
\end{align}
Hence $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is integrable.

Comment: Thank you ! It's very clear!
But I still have a little problem

Comment: Why can we prove integrable by proving I1 and I2 are finite? I thought we have to prove $\intf^+$ and$ \intf^-$ are finite?

Comment: Why can we prove integrable by proving I1 and I2 are finite? I thought we have to prove $ \intf+\int{f^+} $and$\int{f^−}$ are finite?

Comment: I already took the absolute value.

Comment: I got it!  Thanks a lot